# IE11 font issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am using windows 10 with IE11.

I am getting an issue displaying certain fonts like font awesome.

I have been trying for weeks to fix this with all sorts of solutions to no avail so last resort is to ask here.

This is also when browsing external websites like the font awesome site as shown in the screenshot so I can't add anything to the web.config file as I have no access.

I don't believe this is a duplicate of the other questions as has been marked.

I have provided a screenshot of the issue. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: There's a screen shot now

Comment: The duplicates linked above should help you out. Bottom line is, your font lacks embed permissions. This can be fixed using tools, but with questionable legality. It would be better to obtain a font with the correct permissions from the proper source

Comment: For anyone having this issue it was sorted by enabling the windows firewall service.